# Learning Anaysis Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, cubes

Can anyone recommend a good resource -- book, website, article, etc -- to help me learn SQL Server Analysis services.

I have no knowledge of this technology right now but I do constantly work with SQL server in the traditional sense.

I want to learn about Cubes and Using Reporting Services with it. I want to start from the bottom but after I finish with the material, ideally, I'd be able to stumble through a real development project...

I'm hoping to get started with a free resource but if anyone knows of a **really good** book, I'd take that too.

Or, if you don't know of a resource how did you get started with the technology?

Thank you,
Frank

Comment: See my post below for a link to where I answered a similar question in some depth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101242/nice-book-on-sql-server-analysis-services) for a list of AS resources I compiled in answer to a similar question.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty outstanding book:

[Professional SQL Server Analysis Services 2005 with MDX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764579185)

Gives you a good overview of the architecture of SSAS, as well as the query language MDX, and administrative/maintenance overview.  A good primer for a developer OR a system administrator.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I'll try to check this out.

Answer (score 2):

My personal favorite book on the topic is [Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672327821)

Mosha Pasumansky's blog is a great resource once you start learning more about the technology and MDX

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/default.aspx

Comment: I love both of these resources, but I don't know if they are a good place to start. I think they would be of more interest to the intermediate to advanced users.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to [Analysis Services Books online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175609(SQL.90).aspx).  It's a decent resource, and completely free.